# how to create a .exe that should validate if an app this one installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

the problem is that I'm trying to compile a program in c # that depends on virtualbox is installed.

when compiling me not listed as prerequisite virtualbox and could not find a way to validate whether virtualbox installed or not

I would like to know how to create an installer that allows me to validate the above dimensioned

Comment: Get Install Shield LE, follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx then when creating an Install Project add it as a prerequisite.

Comment: wizard and try to project, project setup and install shield proyect but let me add virtualbox as a prerequisite

Comment: Do you want to check if VirtualBox is installed from your app. EXE, or from an MSI?  If MSI, do you use WIX?

Comment: ok. I not use WIX, but  I see that work. you've got a tutorial of that work?